# Mysql trigger help - before insert

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

Edited slightly for formatting reasons.

This is my trigger:

```
delimiter $$

delimiter ;
```

After I run that trigger, I insert a new row into the Employee table and get a "MySQL Error 1136 "Column count does not match value count at row 1". Could someone please point me in the right direction? I'm not looking for anyone to do my homework. Just point out what I've done wrong and what I can do to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: What is the structure of the Lowest_salary table?

Comment: It is the same as the Employee table, but without any foreign keys/references. I will edit it in my original post.

Comment: Are there multiple rows in that table, or a single row?  Please show what values you would like to insert into that table.

Comment: Just a single row. We weren't told exactly what values must be inserted into this new table, just as long as there was some record that showed that a new employee received a salary lower than his/her department peers. I figured inserting the new employee's salary into the table would be sufficient, but apparently it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your insert to this to insert the new record into the Lowest_salary table.

```
INSERT INTO Lowest_salary (LIST FIELDS) VALUES (NEW.FIELD1, NEW.FIELD2, ...);
```

Comment: Ahhhh! I see the error, and such a small one at that! Thanks for your help.